# Flutter transparent background - SingleChildScrollView overflows boundaries with its children's background color

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

the background of my Flutter App has a LinearGradient. I implemented it like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  body: Ink(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        end: Alignment.topRight,
        colors: kGradientBackgroundColor,
      ),
    ),
    child: Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 30, 30, 0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            if (header != null) header,
            body, // THIS BODY
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);}
```

Inside the body (Marked with // THIS BODY), I have a SingleChildScrollView which wraps a ListView.builder containing some ListTiles. The ListTiles have a tileColor associated. When scrolling the ListView the background color of the tiles overflows the container. Except for the ListTile, Buttons, and Text, every other widget is transparent.

The tree inside body looks like this: Column(Column(Header, Divider), Expanded --> SingleChildScrollView --> ScrollBar --> ListView)

How can I avoid the background color overflow? ClipRect is not working.

Over the divider line there, only the gradient should be visible and not the tileColor
[image: img]

Comment: can you add an image of what you have so far

Comment: I have added the picture as an edit to the post.

Comment: Try reducing height of the divider.

Comment: It overflows to the top until the tiles "go out" the window. My guess is that the color should normally be overdrawn by other elements, but since everything is transparent, that does not work.